# How do i match the character succeeding a particular string?

Tags: regex, perl

Currently i am using a perl regex where as a first preference i am intending to match the character ( number or alphanumeric ) immediately succeeding the string "Lecture" else match the last character in absence of string "Lecture" from each line .But it doesnt seem to work very well for my use case. i am adding my whole command below

```
cat 1.txt | perl -ne 'print "$1 \n" while /(?:\w*Lecture)?([^\s]+)$/g;'
```

Note - it might occur that there is no space around the string "Lecture" and the line might not end as .mp4 necessarily

cat 1.txt

```
54282068 Lecture74- AS 29 Question.mp4   
174424104Lecture 74B - AS 29 Theory.mp4   
Branch Accounts Lecture 105
Lecture05 - Practicals AS 28
Submissions 20.mp4
HW Section 77N
```

Expected output

```
74
74B
105
05
20
77N
```

I preferably want a solution which I can directly run in the Cli/Console.
( Just Like my original code - cat 1.txt | perl code ).
I don't want to execute a separate .pl file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` matching either Lecture followed by optional horizontal whitespace chars or assert that Lecture is not present using a negative lookahead.

```
Lecture\h*\K\w+|^(?!.*Lecture).*\h\K[^.\s]+
```

- `Lecture\h*` Match Lecture and optional horizontal whitespace chars
- `\K\w+` Clear the match buffer and match 1+ word chars
- `|` Or
- `^(?!.*Lecture)` Assert that Lecture is not present
- `.*\h` Match till the last horizontal whitespace
- `\K[^.\s]+` Clear the match buffer and match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZpgF5y/1)

Using `\K` you can get the match in this example instead of the capturing group.

For example

```
cat 1.txt | perl -ne 'print "$& \n" while /Lecture\h*\K\w+|^(?!.*Lecture).*\h\K[^.\s]+/g;'
```

Output

```
74
74B
105
05
20
77N
```